# insert into does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Why doesn't the query below work:

```
INSERT INTO [ProcessStatus] ([ProcessId])
SELECT TMP.[ProcessId]

FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT 
     [ProcessId]
FROM [Process]
) TMP
```

error message is (returns added):

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value.
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= 
or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Comment: Gruber, please edit your question to show us the union that you mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: If you have simplified for posting, you have taken the problem out, you code should work as there is no subquery only a derived table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a buggy trigger on the ProcessStatus table.

Comment: What does this have to do with a trigger?

Comment: +1 as it *could* be a bugger trigger. The subquery shown returning multiple rows itself should not be a problem

Comment: Indeed; there's nothing wrong with the statement as far as I can see; it's perfectly acceptable to insert multiple rows using INSERT INTO, so looking into the possibility of weirder things going on, like trigger oddness, isn't a bad idea.

Comment: I agree, if there is no subquery inteh statement, then a trigger is the only possibility left and since so many developers don;t seem to know how to correctly write a trigger to handle multiple row inserts it is even a highly likely problem. I'd bet if there is a trigger it starts with setting some variable to a value from the inserted table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [Process] only has the one field (or any others auto increment), you do not need the sub query. 
Try:

```
insert into [ProcessStatus] ([ProcessId])
select distinct 
     [ProcessId]
FROM [Process]
```

EDIT: if you were just wondering why the error message, it should work, are you sure that is where it's failing?

Comment: original query has an union, thats why I wrote it like that, why is it incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that. It works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE #ProcessStatus (ProcessID INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE #Process (ProcessID INTEGER)

INSERT INTO #Process VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #Process VALUES(2)

INSERT INTO #ProcessStatus (ProcessId)
SELECT TMP.ProcessId
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT 
     ProcessId
FROM #Process
) TMP
```

> (2 row(s) affected)

Are you absolutely sure about what's going on?